# Why is my action not triggering inside of a modal with ember js?

Tags: ember.js

Here is my template code:

```
{{#if showDialog}}
  {{#modal-dialog
    translucentOverlay=true
    containerClass="modal-dialog__container"
    overlayClass="modal-dialog__overlay"
    wrapperClass="modal-dialog"
    }}

    <h1 class="modal-dialog__title">Type your goal here</h1>
    {{input class="settings-row__input"}}

    <div class="wrap_buttons">
      <input {{action "cancelOrgGoal"}} type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn_cancel">
      <input {{action "saveOrgGoal"}} type="button" name="Create" value="Select" class="btn btn_create">
    </div>

  {{/modal-dialog}}
{{/if}}
```

Here is my js code:

```
actions: {
    saveOrgGoal() {
      console.log('hi');

      let orgGoal = store.createRecord('organization-goal', {
        description: 'Rails is Omakase',
      });

      orgGoal.save(); // => POST to '/posts'

      this.set('showDialog', true);
    },
    cancelOrgGoal() {
      console.log('hi');
      this.set('showDialog', false);
    }
  }
```

I am using the addon ember-modal-dialog

When I click on either of the buttons the actions are not triggering and nothing is logged in the js console.

Can anyone see why this is?
Am I doing some silly mistake?

Comment: can you add the file paths for both of those snippets? thanks! :D

Comment: Yes it's frontend/lib/organization-settings/addon/templates/organization-goals.hbs and frontend/lib/organization-settings/addon/routes/organization-goals.js

Comment: Have a [read about controllers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.5.0/controllers/)

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment about file paths, routes can't have actions that are directly callable from the template.

Without extracting a component, you'd want to define your actions on the controller for that route.

- The Route - data access - the value of the model hook is what gets passed on to the controller. Nothing from the route is accessible from the template, aside from the `model`
- The Controller - supports the template, and can define properties and has access to the model
- That template is backed by the controller.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: When I put these actions on the controller they still do not trigger. I thought that seeing as I am doing a save with the data I should use the route no? I always have actions on the route that I call from the template and it usually works

Comment: what version of ember are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.1.1 :D

Comment: can you reproduce this in a fiddle? 
because, this should be working, and I feel like something suuuuuuper tiny is missed somewhere.

I guess, what's the filepath of the controller?
also, can you post the entire files?

Comment: it was the class wrapperClass="modal-dialog" that was causing the problem for some reason. Thank you for your help @nullvoxpopuli